# Remove personal data from text with efficient replace on strings from a word list with 6 million words

Tags: c#, regex, replace, regexp-replace

I'm having trouble with performance on this replace function that I am trying to build. To remove personal information from text posts.

I have thousands of strings looking like this:

> *Hi, the user: f3a11-010101-01a1-1111 is a great co-worker. She lives in Manchester. If you want to contact her, the telephone number is 1111111. /Marcus*

The strings are often much more text.

In the end I want to replace all the info in the text that is in the word-list. The final string will look like this.

> *Hi, the user: [userID] is a great co-worker. She lives in [city]. If you want to contact her, the telephone number is [telephone]. /[Name]*

the wordlist is in lowercase but the function have to be case insensitive.
I have tried several approaches which I have skipped because they are to slow.
What I have now is the fastest. I work with C# 6.

Here is some pseudo code to explain it.

The wordlist is in a dictionary.

```c#
Dictionary<string, string> word = PopulateWordList();
```

I loop through each string with text that can have values that should be replaced.

```
    foreach (var post in objColl)
    {
        string[] substrings = Regex.Split(post.Text, @"( |,|!|\.)");
        replaced = false;
        foreach (string str in substrings)
        {
            if (str.Length > 4)
            {
                stringToCompare = str.ToLower();
                if (word.Keys.Contains(stringToCompare))
                {
                    replaced = true;
                    str = words[stringToCompare];
                }                
            }
        }
        if (replaced)
           post.Text = String.Join("" substrings);
    }
```

This code works but it is slow. The important thing is that words should be matched if they have trailing characters like .?! or signs before them like / and so on. All these signs are not in the above code.

I have also tried splitting the string and populate a hashset and se if they intersect with the dictionary keys. But for that to work you have to lowercase the string first before you split it. And then when you do the replace you have to use the above code to preserve the casing. But no real performence improvements though almost every post have something to replace.

In my real code I also use parallel for each loops but leaved that out in my example.

Things I've tried before this code is with regex replace that can handle ignore case, but that is super slow and to prevent splitting half words you have to add spaces and trailing charcters to the words.

Small example of trashed code:

```
    foreach (var word in wordlist)
    {
        stringWithText = Regex.Replace(stringWithText, ' ' + word.Oldvalue + ' ', ' ' + word.Newvalue + ' ', RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        stringWithText = Regex.Replace(stringWithText, ' ' + word.Oldvalue, '.' + word.Newvalue + '.', RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        stringWithText = Regex.Replace(stringWithText, ' ' + word.Oldvalue, '!' + word.Newvalue + '!', RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //And several more replaces to handle every case. You also have to handle when the word is first or last in the string.
    }
```

I have tried many more ways but nothing that is faster then my first code. This topic I widely discussed and there are many threads on this over the years. I have looked at many but not found any better way.

I'm using a StopWatch to measure the time it takes to go through the same smaller set of posts and wordlist so I know what time it takes with each code change.

Any ideas on how to improve this or if there is a completely different way to solve this? Just don't suggest sending the data to cloud API with an AI language model to solve this as it contains personal data.

There are also problems with conjugations that may not be in the word list or if you have words like "Manchester City". That will be replace with "[city] City"
So my code don't handle words with spacing.

I also know I won't be able to solve this perfectly but it can probably be done better and faster.

Comment: You obvioulsy should read on Regex.Replace (pay attention to MatchEvaluator once), but `if (word.Keys.Contains(stringToCompare))` looks like pure trolling... Why someone wrote that for you?

Comment: word.Keys.Contains(stringToCompare) is a hash match and superfast. Even if you use MatchEvaluator with regexp. That approach would probably be way more slower.

Comment: That is not true - you may want to try to find a docs that says that Keys as O(1) for lookup .

Comment: Do the strings you are trying to replace have unified format? i.e. are they all guids?

Comment: Also for proper benchmarking do not use `StopWatch` but rather BenchmarkDotNet.

Comment: the strings are not all guids

Comment: How big is the word bank? Consider building a  [Trie](https:/ /en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from the word bank  instead of a Dictionary<string,string>.  The Trie can be either case sensitive or not. This should be a lot faster for finding words in the bank.

Comment: 1.2 million words

Answer (score 4):

This part is especially highly suboptimal.

```
if (word.Keys.Contains(stringToCompare))
{
    replaced = true;
    str = words[stringToCompare];
}
```

Change PopulateWordList() so that when it does a `new Dictionary<string, string>()` to use the constructor that allows a comparer, as so: `new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Then change:

```
stringToCompare = str.ToLower();
if (word.Keys.Contains(stringToCompare))
{
    replaced = true;
    str = words[stringToCompare];
}
```

to:

```
if (word.TryGetValue(str, out temp))
{
    replaced = true;
    str = temp;
}
```

And right before the outer foreach, make a `string temp = null;`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply and help me. I'm going to test your suggestions and see the difference.

When you add StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase to the dictionary doesn't it become a sorted dictionary and you lose the hash match functionality?

Searching the binary tree of a sorted dictionary is fast, but searching the hash list that a regular dictionary uses should be a lot faster. I'll be back with test results

Comment: Setting the dictionary to use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is more optimal than using `.ToLower()`.